# Deleting files to improve checkout time

Tags: delete-file, cvs, vcs-checkout

We have a version of our project that we tagged created with rtag -- and it has a large number of files which causes checkout to be exceptionally slow.

A lot of the files are obsolete, so I have deleted them and committed this change to the repository. However, the checkout time has not improved because the files still exist on the server and are subject to processing when a new checkout of this tag is made (but they are not checked out).

Is there some way I can either disable this processing, or permanently delete the files, but not affect any other tags or branches?

Comment: How many commits/versions of the project has there been? Slowness may also be due to that.